# Should I leave comments suggesting that posters improve their formatting?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

Earlier today, I came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28172777/2173917) which I felt was poorly formatted. I left a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172777/p-p-mynode-nullp-nextmynode-null-does-what?noredirect=1#comment44714602_28172777) on that question.

Shortly after, I thought that my comment *might be considered* rude, and  I added a bit of [clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172777/p-p-mynode-nullp-nextmynode-null-does-what?noredirect=1#comment44714809_28172777) of my intention.

However, I got a negative reply [currently deleted, can't link] from the OP. I wrote a polite [well, at least I think it was] reply, to which, I received another [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172777/p-p-mynode-nullp-nextmynode-null-does-what?noredirect=1#comment44715757_28172777) from the OP:

> btr u answer questions from nxt tym than to do such comments.

I have a simple question: am I correct to leave those comments or not?

Comment: I sincerely wonder why anyone would upvote the linked question. Even if one of the answerers corrected the most egregiously bad part. Well, maybe the answerers...

Comment: Smone nds 2 lrn hw 2 spell

Comment: If you felt it was poorly formatted, why didn't you just edit it to fix the formatting?

Comment: Why you didn't remove your first comment which you thought is rude?!

Comment: @KenWhite My thought was first point OP to proper direction so (s)he can correct this instance as well as all future instances. Anyway, just a few minutes later it was edited, anyway. :-)

Comment: @Ahmad I din't think it _was_ rude. I thought someone _might_ apprehend it _as_ rude so I added some clarification.

Comment: You have enough rep to be able to edit questions, right?  Why do you need to leave a comment?

Comment: "btr u nxt tym" what language is this?

Comment: @DavidWallace - to the general point, sometimes you can see that a question is *badly* formatted but you may not be enough of a subject matter expert to do a decent job of repairing it (or may not have enough of a clue of what the OP is actually trying to say) and in that sort of case, I'd usually leave a comment with some hints rather than attempting an edit myself.

Comment: @DavidWallace if I do as you suggest, then OP might come back and ask me why i did not bother to leave a comment first? _[believe me, this has happened with me sometimes back]_.

Comment: Yes, he/she might ask that.  You don't have to answer.  If he/she is too ungracious to say "thank you for fixing up my post", it's really not  your problem.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, you are more than welcome to post comments on how the author of a question can improve it, or to point out problems with the question.  You don't need to answer the question to do this.

If the author is unwilling to improve his question despite its problems, then there really isn't much you can do.  If the question is not useful as it is, downvote it, if it's not an appropriate question on the site, vote to close.  After that just move along and try to find a question where the author is willing to improve their question (or where the question doesn't require improvement).  Continuing to engage in the author after they have demonstrated no attempt to interact constructively is only going to cause problems for everyone involved.

Answer (score 20):

Your last comment ("GL getting answers next time") comes off as a bit sarcastic (even if he deserved it).

That said, your actions looked fine to me. Many OPs will leave comments like that because they just want an answer, they don't want our help in improving their writing (which is truly sad).

I've received many of these kinds of comments, just ignore them unless the OP seems *truly* confused, at which point you could mention that it's important to improve their posts. I wouldn't go there with that poster though.

Comment: well, I don't deny the _sarcasm_ part absolutely, but then also I wanted to point out the fact that (s)he might be missing out the opportunity to get a quality answer because the appearance of the post [and the future ones, if similar] _might_  make people frustrate and move away.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Your intent was correct, I would have said something like "Improving your formatting will generally lead towards a better response towards future questions, including getting more/better answers". In other words, you can get there without the sarcasm if you want.

Comment: Thank you sir. That really makes sense. I'll try to be more expressive next time onward. Thank you for your time and response.

Answer (score 7):

Certainly any effort to increase quality of questions on the site is laudable. Please do continue to leave comments that help askers (and answerers) improve the quality of their posts, if they're doing something obviously wrong.

If you're concerned about too much comment-noise, you can check back in a day to remove your comments and flag other obsolete comments as noisy.

If you are concerned about being rude, you simply need to present the problem not as a *moral issue* ("How dare you post such low-quality drivel! Change your ways, you sinner!") but rather a *matter of strategy* ("If you clean up your question by doing X, you'll probably attract more attention and get better answers.") In that case, it's clear that you and the asker are on the same team: you both want better answers on the site!

If they still take offense at the suggestion that a better-quality question will attract better answers (or that they believe their question's quality is so high that it cannot possibly be improved), then there's nothing more to say to them; move on.

Answer (score 4):

If those were my comments, comments I had left on the question, I would remove the comment if the issue addressed by my comment had already been corrected by an edit (improved formatting, removal of the bold, and so on.)

That's just my personal opinion.

That's based on the current state of the question.

For the future reader, someone that sees the question for the first time... a comment such as "Why are you shouting?" just seems out of place on the current question.

It may have been appropriate earlier, but it just doesn't seem to be relevant now, and seems more a distraction than helpful at this point. (I'm thinking here about the future reader.)

(Then again, to a question phrased as "**I want ...**", my typical response is "Well, I want a pony and free pizza".)