# Failed an audit, when I only intended to leave a comment

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I just failed an audit. It was an answer presented as a first post by a new user, with the text:

> When the Sup constructor calls printA() it executes the printA method of class Sub (which overrides the method of the same name of class Sup), so it returns the value of the a variable of class Sub, which is still 0, since the instance variables of Sub are not yet initialized (they are only initialized after the Sup constructor is done).

The entire answer is a single sentence, which I felt hurts readability. I decided to leave a comment noting that formatting could be improved.

[Turns out this was an answer by @Eran](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17289127), and I failed because apparently commenting on a good post in a review is bad?

I'm not posting this to rant, because it's not a big deal. It just seems like a very odd reason to fail someone. Afaik, audits are to prevent robot voting, and to ensure real people understand how to review and are actually caring to be accurate. I'm not a robot, looked at the answer for probably thirty seconds, and decided that a comment would be a good addition.

Am I wrong here?

Comment: In other queues the add comment link causes to reveal it is an audit. This should be implemented on First Posts as well.

Comment: While I generally agree that trying to add a comment probably shouldn't fail an audit, and that the review queues are broken in all sorts of frustrating ways, you admitting that you wanted "to leave a comment noting that formatting could be improved" is evidence that the audit failure was correct in this case. Such a comment would be noise, and shouldn't be left by anyone. If the formatting needs to be improved, then you should edit the post. Anyone can edit, including brand-new users, and you even have full editing privileges.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't see how that should be the correct course. When I see a new user who has unformatted code, I could either fix their code for them, or tell them how to do it. The former doesn't teach them anything unless they actually check the edit. The latter actually allows them to learn how to fix their mistakes for the future. "Just fix it for them" hardly seems like a good strategy when it's clearly a lack of knowledge on their part. For this case, they may be unaware that they posted a run-on sentence until it's pointed out, or that the formatting could be improved.

Comment: Use the edit summary to teach by example.

Comment: @CodyGray But unless they know about the editing system, how will they even know to look there? It just seems hiding that information is unhelpful.

Comment: @CodyGray That also seems to contradict https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284710/3000206, although that post was kind of diluted with another issue.

Comment: I...don't see the contradiction. Telling people to fix their own mistakes rarely goes over well, and it certainly doesn't help the future viewers to the site. The information isn't hidden; notifications are issued when posts are edited in a non-trivial fashion.

Comment: @CodyGray I meant contradicting the post I linked to. It seems to suggests that comments should be left.

Comment: It doesn't really suggest that they *should* be left. Servy's answer just says you are welcome to do so. I'm saying that's not the *most useful* thing you could do, and these types of comments just create more work for moderators to have to go and clean up when they become obsolete (which they do *very* quickly). More importantly, leaving a comment is *not* the purpose of the review queue. The purpose of the review queue is to *fix* problems.

Comment: @CodyGray Ok, I'll try to change my habits.