# Permitted to add comment to 'audit' question; comment was then silently removed

Tags: discussion, review-audits

When reviewing in 'First Posts' I looked at this question [What's the point of verifying the number of times a function is called with Mockito?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52222264/whats-the-point-of-verifying-the-number-of-times-a-function-is-called-with-mock) and got interested in the content (as opposed to the quality) of the question; so (after some thought) I added a comment and pressed 'I'm Done'. My comment was not aimed at indicating any problem with the question, but the 'No Action Needed' button was greyed out because I'd added the comment, so I assumed 'I'm Done' would be fine. I then received an audit failure message, with which I disagreed, but never mind. My concern is that my comment was silently removed. I do realise that it may have been of zero interest to anyone, but nonetheless this seems pretty unfriendly, given that my assumption is that the audit feature is intended to ensure care is taken; if anything, I probably erred in the other direction. Should I have pressed 'Skip' instead of 'I'm Done'?

Comment: Weird, that's not how I remember audits working... I thought FP audits ended after any action taken, and I thought commenting would *pass* a positive audit.

Comment: @Stephen I guess as I'd failed the audit my comment was automatically deleted on the erroneous assumption that it was a 'do better' type comment ... I have seen other meta discussions re providing an 'I disagree' button - that might have been useful in this case I think.

Comment: I thought audits ended the moment you clicked the "add comment" link (whether pass or fail).

Comment: @Draco18s I remember that I wrote nice comment few times to asker, just to receive audit message. It was irritating - I spent time to type sentence or two, just to get it dismissed (that's why I remeber that).

Comment: I think this is new behaviour that I first noticed last week or so. A comment then `SKIP` was occasionally how I handled audits.

Comment: @MandyShaw Audit are like "sandboxes". No action you take will affect the actual question (in fact often they change the number of votes displayed to not give away that the audit is a deleted question with -25 votes). This is by design, so I don't think it should be changed. IMHO the only thing I'd change is to just fail/pass the audit when the "add comment" button is clicked instead of waiting for the "I'm done".

Comment: If it's sandboxed.. then does commenting basically do nothing? any point in the option being there?

Comment: @Scriptable If you remove the comment box, makes it very easy for a robo reviewer to know that it's an audit. The kind of things we want the audit to catch. It's a difficult one, because we want people to do reviews correctly and we measure that slightly with audits. However audits should be sandboxed and not affect the underlying question. This isn't an easy one to solve I feel....

Comment: see also: [Failed an audit, when I only intended to leave a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356356/839601)

Comment: I'm even more irritated now, having over the last few days encountered a load of completely obvious spam audit questions which are surely a complete waste of space - you'd have to be on the planet Zog not to spot them.

Comment: I've just failed an audit on this: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/22543485 for adding a comment suggesting (gently) that the argument would be clearer with a single statement of the problem (and, potentially, if shortened). I was not trying to say that the question was bad, just spending time trying to make it clearer to the viewer. Now, of course, my comment has vanished altogether. Surely reviewing should always be an opportunity to comment on possible improvements, however fantastic the question? I usually enjoy reviewing, but this sort of thing really puts me off.

Comment: I think the code has been changed! Just now I attempted to save a comment on a 'good' audit question and got a little message saying 'This is an audit'. Would have been better if this had happened as soon as I hit Add Comment, but definitely an improvement on the previous state of affairs.